# Shell script to download all webpages?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

I am trying to download a range of pages from a site.

The `URL` would be in the format: `http://example.com/x` where `x` could be any `number` from `100` to `200`.

Is there any possible script that I could use to download all of the pages, ranging from `example.com/100` to `example.com/200` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in {100..200}; do
    wget "http://example.com/$x"
done
```

Comment: I prefer to demonstrate the habit of quoting variables unless you want them to undergo word splitting and globbing. I know it's not an issue in this script, but it means he's less likely to run into an issue in other scripts where quoting the variable is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for always quoting, and showing this good practice even if not absolutely necessary. @BeniBela: always use quotes!

Comment: Funny, I wrote `"$x"` at first and then edited the comment to remove " because it was pointless. But that is not the point. The point is that you should never use `"` quotes for urls and should use `'` , because urls can contain `$` characters and they mess everything up. And second, he should end the line with `&`, so all the wgets are run in parallel, and it is 100 times faster than your version.

Comment: That's different, if the constant part of the URL contains `$`, then it does need to be in single quotes. Then it would be `'http://blah/foo$bar/'"$x"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `curl` installed, you might want to use the relatively efficient following way:

```
curl -O 'http://example.com/[100-200]'
```

(yes, I know, `curl` is really cool!).

Answer (score 0):

Faster version that does not risk breaking more complex urls with incorrect quoting:

```
for x in {100..200}; do
    wget 'http://example.com/'"$x" &
done
wait
```

Comment: It's not clear the server will appreciate you sending 100 simultaneous requests at it. Browsers tend to limit themselves to something like 4 concurrent connections to a server.